# Sometime Except Combo Box's SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I have one Combo box and it has SelectedIndexChanged Event but i want Ignore that event in some case how can i achieve that functionality.

describe code is below

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
        lstString.Add("One");
        lstString.Add("Two");
        lstString.Add("Three");

        foreach (string str in lstString)
            cBox.Items.Add(str);

        //Here I want Ignore cbox_SelectedIndexChanged Event
        cBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

private void cBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your Selected Item is :- " + cBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by except ? Ignore it ? In this case you would have to test if the id == 0 in the event handler OR wire your event in code rather than in the designer after setting the index to 0.

Comment: thanks for replay but when application is run at that time use select index 0 at that time i don't want ignore. I mean I want ignore that event many time and this is sample code not my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose either of the 2 approaches.

1. Have a bool flag which will be set for those conditions when you want to ignore the event handler from running. And use that flag inside your `SelectedIndexChanged` method
2. Subscribe to the event only after you have set `cBox.SelectedIndex=0` if that is the only case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subscribing the event within the designer (I expect you to do this at the moment) you can subscribe to the event in code after the initialization is done.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Init stuff
    cBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // Event subscription
    cBox.SelectedIndexChanged += cBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void cBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your Selected Item is :- " + cBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```